# Is there a way to automate creation of subscriptions in SSRS 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have development, test, demo and production systems. They all need to have the same set of reports (easily deployed via Visual Studio, multiple reports at the same time if needed) and the same set of report subscriptions. At this time I have to manually go through the sequence of up to 7 steps in web UI for report manager to deploy or modify each subscription on each system.

Is there a way to automate/improve creation/modification of report subscriptions? I use SSRS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I've cheated in the past and manipulated the reporting database in SQL Server, you could dig around in there and see if you can figure out the records you need to add.